# How to draw transparent background in webGL on canvas

Tags: css, webgl, shader

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zMRjwv

In that page, I want to draw a transparent background but it's not working when I use `gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

```
 const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl', {alpha: false});
```

Set `alpha:false` is also can't because 2D context 
attributes: alpha: Boolean that indicates if the canvas contains an alpha channel.

If set to false, the browser will knows that the backdrop is always opaque, which can speed up drawing of transparent content and `images.WebGL` context.

```
attributes:
alpha: Boolean that indicates if the canvas contains an alpha buffer.
```

Comment: Tried to make sense of the original question and improve it.

Comment: I'm sorry but 1,000 lines of code are not a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zMRjwv)

Comment: I'm sorry I just want to draw transparent background or 2d imge in webgl 3D.

Comment: A lot of answers tell me set gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0).
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl', {alpha: false});But that's wrong.

Comment: You can't have a transparent background with alpha:false.. Alpha:false = 100% opaque period.

Comment: So how do I draw a transparent background using WEBGL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the sample you linked to is that the sample itself is not transparent. It draw a background, then it draws sakura petals, then it applies a glow shader to give the petals a glow. This generates an opaque image so setting the canvas alpha to true (or not setting it all) won't make a difference.

To make it transparent comment out the following lines and change the background color

```
// gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, renderSpec.mainRT.frameBuffer);
// gl.viewport(0, 0, renderSpec.mainRT.width, renderSpec.mainRT.height);
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// renderBackground();
renderPointFlowers();
// renderPostProcess();
```

You can then possibly adjust the petal brightness changing this line

```
col *= mix(0.8, 1.0, pow(abs(coord.x), 0.3));
```

to this for example

```
col *= mix(1.8, 3.0, pow(abs(coord.x), 0.3));
```

Comment: Problem solved.Thank you very much.And apologize for my actions.I asked for an example of nearly a 1000 lines of code.I'm so sorry and grateful.